# Can't pull down the "manage external users" permission metadata for profiles

Tags: deployment, permissions, profile, metadata, ant

I want to be able to store the "manage external users" permission for profiles in a repository, but I haven't be able to identify what metadata tag is associated to it. Every time I deploy to an org via ant this permission is getting set to false - what do I need to include in my package xml to be able to pull down this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce can be a jungle to navigate sometimes. Had to pull down Profile enabling/disabling the `Manage External Users` to understand what is the User permission `name` corresponding to this permission.

It turns out the name you are looking for is `ManagePartners`. Add this under `userPermissions` section of the profile.